# Gnuplot enhanced mode: Using font with spaces in name

Tags: fonts, label, gnuplot

I would like to print a character in a label slanted. Apparently the only way to do it, is to change the font

```
set xlabel "not italics, {/Times-Italic italics}"
```

But what do I do if my font name has spaces in it? Like `MS Reference Sans Serif Kursiv`? Putting quotes around the name results in an error, or prints the whole string. Not putting quotes also prints the string without the `MS`.

Comment: Never mind, just realized it is a terminal issue. Can I delete the question somehow?

Comment: use the `flag` link at the bottom of the question and ask a moderator to delete. +1 for good citizenship!

Comment: Or you can answer the question yourself and give a short working example with terminal and font settings